# Click multiple series of buttons

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Angular application which I would like to automate using Selenium Web Driver.

I tried to implement this code to automate a series of dialog windows with OK buttons:

```
// We check if Survey exit window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, SURVEY_EXIT_BUTTON_ID_LOCATOR, "Survey exit window");

// Wait Progress bar to finish
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));

// We check if Select Equipment Ok window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, MESSAGE_CONTROLLER_SELECTEQUIPMENT_OK_BUTTON, "Select Equipment Ok window");

// Wait Progress bar to finish
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));

// We check if Ok window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, MESSAGE_CONTROLLER_OK_BUTTON_ID_LOCATOR, "Ok window");

// Wait Progress bar to finish
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));

// We check if Select Equipment Exit window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, SURVEY_SELECTEQUIPMENT_EXIT_BUTTON, "Select Equipment Exit window");
```

Method

```
private void clickConfirmWindow(WebDriver driver, String element_id, String name){
    // We check if warning window is displayed using button ID
    System.out.println("Searching " + name + " using " + element_id);
    Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.id(element_id)).size() > 0;
    if(isPresent)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        System.out.println("Found " + name + " using " + element_id);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(element_id)));
        webElement.click();
     }
}
```

For some reason sometimes some of the buttons are not clicked and the code fails.
Many times the code is executed successfully. Is there some better way to organize this series of clicks?

Comment: What error is received on failure and on what code line?

Comment: Are you using the `clickConfirmWindow()` each time the element is expected to be presented?

Comment: @Eliyahu some random button is just not pressed. yes I use it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue causing the intermittent success is your `clickConfirmWindow()` method.

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.id(element_id)).size() > 0;
```

This line doesn't wait... it just checks and if it's false, it assumes it's not going to ever pass and skips that click. You need to add a reasonable wait here to ensure that if the element is coming, it's given a chance to load. In your code, you are wanting to wait for the element to be clickable so I wrote the method `isClickable()`.

```
private Boolean isClickable(String element_id, int timeOut) {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(element_id)));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

if the element is clickable, returns true. If it isn't, it waits up until `timeOut` and returns false if it never succeeds.

As for the rest of your code, I have a few suggestions.

1. There is the concept of DRY (don't repeat yourself) in programming. You can do some googling but basically if you see code used multiple times, consider putting it in a method. One instance I see of this in your code is where you wait for the progress bar to finish. That line is called 3 times so I would put it in a method. It not only makes your code easier to read, it also makes it easier to maintain in case you need to change the wait, change the locator, etc.

   ```
   private void waitForProgressBar() {
       new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));
   }
   ```
2. If your `WebDriverWait()` uses the same timeout, you can declare a variable and reuse it.

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
   wait.until(...);
   ```
3. I didn't rewrite this part but you really should be storing locators as `By` and not IDs as `String`. If you have other elements that you want to use methods on that aren't located by ID, you'll need to write an entirely new method with basically the same code to use it. A simple example...

   ```
   private void click(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
       driver.findElement(locator).click();
   }
   ```

   and then call it using

   ```
   click(driver, By.id("someId"));
   ```

   This method can be used with all locator types... ID, CSS selector, XPath, etc.

Putting this all together,

```
// We check if Survey exit window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, SURVEY_EXIT_BUTTON_ID_LOCATOR, "Survey exit window");

// Wait Progress bar to finish
waitForProgressBar();

// We check if Select Equipment Ok window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, MESSAGE_CONTROLLER_SELECTEQUIPMENT_OK_BUTTON, "Select Equipment Ok window");

// Wait Progress bar to finish
waitForProgressBar();

// We check if Ok window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, MESSAGE_CONTROLLER_OK_BUTTON_ID_LOCATOR, "Ok window");

// Wait Progress bar to finish
waitForProgressBar();

// We check if Select Equipment Exit window is displayed using button ID
clickConfirmWindow(driver, SURVEY_SELECTEQUIPMENT_EXIT_BUTTON, "Select Equipment Exit window");
```

Support methods

```
private void clickConfirmWindow(WebDriver driver, String element_id, String name) {
    // We check if warning window is displayed using button ID
    System.out.println("Searching " + name + " using " + element_id);
    if (isClickable(element_id, 10)) {
        System.out.println("Found " + name + " using " + element_id);
        driver.findElement(By.id(element_id)).click();
    }
}

private void waitForProgressBar() {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-loading-text center-center' and starts-with(., 'Loading')]")));
}

private Boolean isClickable(String element_id, int timeOut) {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(element_id)));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess adding some wait condition inside `clickConfirmWindow()` will resolve the problem.
So instead

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.id(element_id)).size() > 0;
        if(isPresent)
```

where you checking the element presence immediately use something like
`if(waitForElementToBeVisible(element,10))`
where `waitForElementToBeVisible` is

```
public boolean waitForElementToBeVisible(By element, int delay) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, delay);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
            return true;
        }catch (Throwable t){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

or just simply add some small delay of 200-500 milliseconds before `driver.findElements(By.id(element_id))`
The simple delay can be achieved by

```
    public void wait(int delay){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Using the `wait.until(ExpectedConditions` methods are the best practice in `Selenium`, not using the hardcoded fixed delays

Comment: Can you extend the code a little bit? Now I get a delay in code execution.

Comment: Are you asking about simple, dummy delay?

Comment: I need to click on button when it's ready to be clickable because I want the code to be very quickly executed.

Comment: In this case you should use `waitForElementToBeVisible()` method based on `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` selenium method. It polls the DOM with some high enough frequency and continues to the next statement once element state is detected as expected.

Comment: This way is also much more correct as a best practice instead of using hardcoded fixed delays

Comment: I will test it but I suspect it will fail because when buttons appear over the screen there is "drop" animation and Selenium maybe will treat them as displayed while they are not clickable while the animation is running.

Comment: You are right. In this case you should first wait until the animation element is disappeared. However I see in your code you always first waiting for the element to disappear with `invisibilityOfElementLocated` method and only after that using your `clickConfirmWindow` method where, as I understand, the problem occurs because the element is not present yet.